# collapsed a ListItem from a listView

Tags: c#, wpf, setter, stackpanel, multidatatrigger

I have a list view which contain a stack panel. which contain a data grid.

I want that the user will click on a check box.
and some of the data will collapsed. (and rest of the data will go up) for any list view Item

will be appericate some help with code exmpale:

attching some of my XAML code:

```
<Style x:Key="ShowHideStyle" TargetType="StackPanel" >
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Value="True">
                    <Condition.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource V_converter }">
                            <Binding Path="Type"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="NodeID"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="TLV"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Condition.Binding>
                </Condition>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ListView x:Name="LV" ItemsSource= "{Binding  Lggv}" SelectionChanged="dataGridData_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DT" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="LVSP" DataContextChanged="LVSP_DataContextChanged" SourceUpdated="LVSP_SourceUpdated" Style="{StaticResource ShowHideStyle}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"  >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="55"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" Text="{Binding Info }" AllowDrop="True"   FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding Visibility_Header}" >

                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <!-- this is the default background-->
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFCEE6C6" Offset="0.008"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF9ECF8C" Offset="0.987"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Grid x:Name="GridData">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter }">
                            <Binding Path="Type"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="NodeID"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="TLV"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}"  ></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComPort}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" ></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Do you want the header to always be visible?

Comment: the header of the grid view or the header of the List view

Comment: I was referring to the "header" Border in the StackPanel.

Comment: the can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ItemContainerStyle` for the targettype `ListViewItem` instead of targeting your item content (`StackPanel`).

In Resources section, define your style

```
<Style x:Key="ShowHideStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    ...
</Style>
```

Then use it

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShowHideStyle}" .../>
```

Ofcourse, I assume that your converter/trigger thing is actually working and you just have the problem of properly hiding the whole list entry.

Answer (score 0):

Put the StackPanel in an Expander and apply the style to the latter.

```
<ListView x:Name="LV" ItemsSource= "{Binding  Lggv}" SelectionChanged="dataGridData_SelectionChanged" 
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DT" >
            <Expander Header="..." Style="{StaticResource ShowHideStyle}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LVSP" DataContextChanged="LVSP_DataContextChanged" SourceUpdated="LVSP_SourceUpdated">
                    <Border...></Border...>
                    <Grid...></Grid...>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Instead of setting the Visbility property to Collapsed/Visible you set the IsExpanded property of the Expander to false/true:

```
<Style x:Key="ShowHideStyle" TargetType="Expander" >
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Value="True">
                    <Condition.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource V_converter }">
                            <Binding Path="Type"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="NodeID"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="TLV"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Condition.Binding>
                </Condition>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: no this not I Meant
I want the are visible will be shown and goes up!